# Powering 600 WS2811 5V LEDs by using larger voltage power supply and DC:DC convertors close to the LEDs

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, led-strip, switching-regulator

I am working on designing a device that will have about 600 WS2811 5V LEDs on it. I am trying to figure out a way to power all these LEDs. At about 60mA max per led this is about 36 amps of power required.

This is for a piece of art that hangs on the wall, so I really don't want to have to run a bunch of +5V power supplies and multiple wires up to the artwork.

I am considering running a higher voltage power supply (maybe 36V) to the artwork and then using some type of DC-DC module to power smaller segments of the LEDs (to be mounted behind the artwork). This will enable to me to use smaller gauge wire to the artwork itself and just sprinkle around these modules to power maybe 75 LEDS 4.5Amps?

Is my thought on this realistic? Any brand/types of modules I should be looking for?

Comment: Why not run 120V and then adapters regulate from there?

Comment: It needs 180W, that will be hot art, hope you have copper backing. Consider a $30 300W PSU

Comment: 24v or 48v are more standard voltages that you will be able to find supplies for. I think your on the right track to use this as a distribution voltage and buck it down to 5v at the point of use.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Are you talking about a PC power supply?

Comment: @Passerby I think for safety reasons really I want to keep the higher voltage contained.

Comment: Obviously go shop much cheaper but size of a half height 5.25” HDD

Answer (score 1):

that sounds like a good plan.

If you are a struggling artist there are inexpensive DCDC modules available on-line. I like the ones from QSKJ  and "MH" (QSKJ has a website, MH you'll have to search "online marketplace" for.

If you are a professional artist the likes of Traco and MuRata make DC-DC modules that cost more and are possibly better quality.

All theses manufacturers seem to test their modules in a blizzard if you don't want to use a cooling fan run them below about 60% of their claimed capacity. I'd use 5A modules but only ask 3A from each.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking I'll design a little PC Board which has 48V input on one side, and 5V output on the other side with the DC/DC in the middle and a small filtering capacitor. I agree with your suggestion that I need to worry about heat. I'm going to start looking at units which might work.

Do these units typically require other components/passives or just the dc/dc itself?

Comment: Am I right seeing that these modules are like $20-$60/each? Yikes!

Comment: @Jasen you probably can find cheap Chinese units on eBay or Amazon etc...

Comment: Yes that's what i mean by "online marketplace"